# Tabbing in aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I have following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)}\\
V &= 5  &T_1 &= \SI{0,12}{\s}  &T_2 &= \SI{0,25}{\s} &T_3 &= \SI{0,005}           {\s}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Which creates:
[image: Output]

How can i get the first line centered, and the second tabbed but also centered? Is there a way to ignore the alignment?

Thanks :)

Comment: i wouldn't bother trying to use `align*`.  i'd use `gather*` and just put `\qquad` between the segments on the second line.

Comment: if you do not want alignment why use `align`  use perhaps `multline` or `gather`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of `gather` and inserting `quad`s between elements of the second line:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)}\\
V  = 5\quad 
T_1 = \SI{0,12}{\s}\quad  
T_2 = \SI{0,25}{\s}\quad
T_3 = \SI{0,005}{\s}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

this is how i'd set these two lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)}\\[2pt]
V = 5  \qquad T_1 = \SI{0,12}{\s} \qquad  T_2 = \SI{0,25}{\s}
  \qquad T_3 = \SI{0,005}{\s}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

note that you really don't want to have `\\` at the end of a multi-line display using an `amsmath` structure.

Answer (score 3):

Should you have several lines with alignments, but not all, you can use `aligned` or `alignedat` inside a `gather` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)}\\
\begin{alignedat}{4}
V &= 5 &\qquad T_1 &= \SI{0,12}{\s} &\qquad T_2 &= \SI{0,25}{\s} &\qquad T_3 &= \SI{0,005} {\s}\\
W &= 5 &\qquad T_1 &= \SI{0,12}{\s} &\qquad T_2 &= \SI{0,25}{\s} &\qquad T_3 &= \SI{0,005} {\s}
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need tabbing for what you describe.  Here I use a TABstack (without any tabs).  I place a `\quad` between entries on the 2nd line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[
\tabbedstackunder[10pt]{
F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)}
}{
V = 5  \quad T_1 = \SI{0,12}{\s}  \quad T_2 = \SI{0,25}{\s} \quad T_3 = \SI{0,005}           {\s}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give more visual prominence to the values of the four variables, you could use an `align*` environment with a single common alignment point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F_S(p) &= \frac{V}{(1+pT_1)  (1+pT_2)  (1+pT_3)}\\
V   &= 5\\ 
T_1 &= \SI{0,12}{\s}\\
T_2 &= \SI{0,25}{\s}\\ 
T_3 &= \SI{0,005}{\s}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are simply two lines of displayed math. I don't see any thing more natural than using two `\[ ... \]`s.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\begin{document}

\[ F_S(p) = \frac{V}{(1+pT_1) \cdot (1+pT_2) \cdot (1+pT_3)} \]
\[ V=5 \quad T_1=\SI{0,12}{\s} \quad T_2=\SI{0,25}{\s} \quad T_3=\SI{0,005}{\s} \]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Oh, no!  Please don’t set two consecutive, but separate displayed equations: use `gather` (or `gather*`) instead!  This answer would actually deserve a downvote… :-(